# How do I make the style="background-image: url()" in the html div go into css so that I could style it?

Tags: html, css, background-image

How do I make the style="background-image: url()" in the html div go into css so that I could style it? I tried putting it in different divs, but I keep doing something wrong. Since it's class is two words, I can't style that for some reason... Would I have to style it in html?

Here is what I'm working with:

```
    <div id="home-slider" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active" style="background-image: url(images/logo.png)" >
      <div class="caption">
        <h1 class="animated fadeInLeftBig">The **** Organization  </h1>
        <p class="animated fadeInRightBig">****</p>
        <a data-scroll class="btn btn-start animated fadeInUpBig" href="#rescue">****</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit--Some of you have asked for the css for the html, so here it is also

```
#home-slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  attachment: fixed;
  size: cover;
  repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

}



#home-slider .caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -104px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 15;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 2em;
}

#home-slider .caption h1 {
  color: #fff;
  size: 72px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  vertical-align: center;

}


.item, .active { background-image: url(images/logo.png); } {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
}

.item { background-image: url(images/logo.png); } {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
}

.active { background-image: url(images/logo.png); } {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
}



.caption .btn-start {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding:14px 40px;
  border: 2px solid #6e6d6c;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.caption .btn-start:hover {
  color: #fff
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /*  just in case if I want the image to be "parallax"
  background-attachment: fixed;
  */
  background-position: center;
  background-color: #6e6d6c;

}



.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: `.item.active { background-image: url(images/logo.png); }`?

Comment: That doesn't work when I put it in css...

Comment: Maybe the url isn't correct. Can you check the developer tools?

Comment: Everything is correct, and the image is showing in the demo, but I want to make it so that I can edit the width and height of the background image even though the _background_ of the background-image is full screen (so the image would be floating in the center of a background color thats full screen).

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you remove the inline styles once you set it on the external css, otherwise inline will override external.

From this:

```
<div class="item active" style="background-image: url(images/logo.png)">
```

to

```
<div class="item active">
```

- If you are unable to remove the inline styles, you can override it using `!important`.

Like so:

```
.item.active {
  background-image: url(images/logo.png) !important;
}
```

Snippet below (switched to a placehold.it image just for demonstration):

```css
.item.active {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/200x200);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="home-slider" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="caption">
        <h1 class="animated fadeInLeftBig">The **** Organization  </h1>
        <p class="animated fadeInRightBig">****</p>
        <a data-scroll class="btn btn-start animated fadeInUpBig" href="#rescue">****</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I do this, I loose the image, and all that is on the screen is the background color that I had set previously.

Comment: Likely you are not loading the external style.css correctly, have you checked that? let me know if you need advice on it, ideally you would load it inside your `<head></head>` tags, with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourStylesFileName.css">`.

Answer (score 0):

Classes in HTML are separated by a space, so for that div you're trying to style what you have right now is 2 classes -- ".item" and ".active". In your CSS file or between `<style></style>` tags you would need to add:

```
.item { background-image: url(images/logo.png); }
```

or

```
.active { background-image: url(images/logo.png); }
```

depending on the class you're trying to target.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put both classes you need a "," among them. otherwise you are looking for a class inside a class

Try this
.item, .active { background-image: url(images/logo.png); }

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will work using
    .item.active { background-image: url(images/logo.png); } 
If it did not, I think maybe it is something wrong with the codes you define it. 
Could you please show the codes how you define the css which does not work for you?

-----edit-----

I think the problem is the relative path. The css file must be in the different directory from the html file, right? So when you define the backgournd-url in the html file, the root path of the relative path is the directory of the html file, when you define it in css file, the root path is the directory of the css file. So I advice you use the absolute path to define the image url.

Comment: I have edited my question to show the css if you could take another look at it.