# How to change html background-image using the css style tag?

Tags: css

I have been trying to set a background-image for my html page using css but I am having some issues doing it. When I used this code below it worked though

```
<style>
html  {background-image: url("D:/HtML5/astronomytweak/img/andromeda.jpg");}
</style>
```

but when I try using this one that I am suppose to upload to the online server it is not working. Below is the one I'm trying to use and is not working.

`<style>
html  {background-image: url("img/andromeda.jpg");}
</style>`

Please I need help with this challenge. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make the style="background-image: url()" in the html div go into css so that I could style it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45624017/how-do-i-make-the-style-background-image-url-in-the-html-div-go-into-css-so)

Comment: Are your `html/css` files in same directory with `img/adromeda.jpg`? You could have a wrong path in `url("...")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set relative path (./)

```
<style>
html  {background-image: url("./img/andromeda.jpg");}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

try changing html to body

```
<style>
  body  {background-image: url("D:/HtML5/astronomytweak/img/andromeda.jpg");}
</style>
```

Comment: Since I'm trying to upload it on online server, I want the url to be something like this ("img/andromeda.jpg"). Can that be possible?

Comment: The path you would use for the image would be relative to the html file